# Make android launcher with html

Tags: android, react-native, android-launcher

How can I make new android launcher like nova or etc Using JavaScript?

1_How list apps and add them to HTML?

2_How run apps inside JavaScript?

3_How Change system settings?

Can I Use React native or etc to make Android launcher?

Comment: If you want to create a native android application the most common way is java or kotlin.